# Android: How can i do bottomnavigation with fragment in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

i need to do a bottomnavigation with fragment in jetpack compose but can't find any examples yet... I Can someone give a example please?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you get the latest stable version of Android Studio then got to: File -> New Project-> Bottom Navigation Activity -> Finish. This will set up for you 3 fragments with Jetpack Navigation UI.
Also go through the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate)